# What is the 2's complement of -17?

Tags: digital-logic

What will be the binary value of -17 and how to find the 2's complement of -17?

Comment: [Wikipedia is your friend.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an 8-bit word, start with the binary form of 17.  = 00010001

Then invert the bits: = 11101110

Then just add 1: = 11101111.

If you've got a 16-, 32- or 64-bit word then you'll have a load more leading 1s.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not assume anything, you have to just keep the leftmost bit significant. 
Start with the word itself, 10001.
Then invert gives the one's, 01110
Now add 1 to this number. 01111.
But to keep the left most bit significant, append a one there eg,101111
in terms of the minimum number of bits required (6 here).